# Convert complex entries in a matrix to their magnitude

Tags: matlab

I have matrix say a in matlab. I wish to some feature selection using relieff function.

The problem I have is that some values in the matrix are complex numbers. How can I convert the complex numbers to represent their magnitude in the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the complex valued entries in your matrix `A` using

```
cmplx = imag(A) ~= 0;
```

Once you found them, you can replace them

```
A(cmplx) = abs( A(cmplx) );
```

Note that requiring floating-point numbers to be exactly zero might be too restrictive and a threshold might be needed instead, e.g.,

```
cmplx = abs( imag(A) ) > 1e-8;
```

Comment: How about just using "newa = abs(a);" . Would that effect other values as well?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia `abs(A)` will convert all your negative real entries to positive ones - not sure this is what you want.

Comment: You could, more simply, use `A = real(A);`, if you want to keep the sign of the real part

Comment: @LuisMendo taking the `real` part is **not** the same as taking the magnitude of complex numbers.

Comment: @Shai Of course. That'w why I said "if you want to keep the sign of the real part". I made the comment just in case that's what the OP wants (it would make more sense to me)

Comment: @Shai Yeah thanks, that makes more sense. You can please inform why floating point numbers have imaginary parts?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia imaginary part is not directly related to floating point. the thing is that if you make some floating point computation that may results with complex numbers or strictly real numbers you cannot assume the imaginary part of the strictly real results will be **exactly** zero due to floating point precision.